# Reference to captured var in concurrently-executing code

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, swift-concurrency

I was trying out the new async/await pattern in swift and I came accross something which I found it confusing.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View  {
        Text("Hello World!")
            .task {
                var num = 1

                Task {
                    print(num)
                }

                Task {
                    print(num)
                }
            }
    }

    func printScore() async {
        var score = 1

        Task { print(score) }
        Task { print(score) }
    }
}
```

[image]

Can someone please clarify looking at the above screenshot on why the compiler only complaints about captured `var` inside `printScore()`  function and does not complaint when the same is being done using the `task` modifier on the `body` computed property of the `ContentView` struct (i.e Line 14-24) ?

This is the example I came up with and got confused on the compiler behavior.I also change the compiler setting "Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting to “Complete” and still don't see the compiler complaining.

Comment: There is no need for `Task` there, any of them. you only need `.task`

Comment: Well that's true but just for the fun of experimental example sake, why is there no compiler error inside the `body` computed property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a special power of `@MainActor`. In a View, `body` is tagged MainActor:

```
@ViewBuilder @MainActor var body: Self.Body { get }
```

Tasks inherit the context of their caller, so those are are also MainActor. If you replace `Task` with `Task.detached` in `body`, you will see the same error, since this will move the Task out of the MainActor context.

Conversely, if you add `@MainActor` to `printScore` it will also compile without errors:

```
@MainActor func printScore() async {
    var score = 1

    Task { print(score) }
    Task { print(score) }
}
```

`score` inherits the MainActor designation, and is protected. There is no concurrent access to `score`, so this is fine and correct.

This actually applies to all actors, but I believe the compiler has a bug that makes things not quite behave the way you expect. The following code compiles:

```
actor A {
    var actorVar = 1
    func capture() {
        var localVar = 1
        Task {
            print(actorVar)
            print(localVar)
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you remove the reference to `actorVar`, the closure passed to Task will not be put into the actor's context, and that will make the reference to `localVar` invalid. IMO, [this is a compiler bug](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/63773).